# I can't get scroll bars with swing

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist, jscrollbar

I have two different places scroll bars should appear.

One is a JTable inside of a JScrollPane. I want the JTable to be a constant size with scrollbars appearing if it's too big, and it not filling the pane if it's too small. Instead, it just stretches to fill the allotted space.

The other is a vertical JList that's in a dialog box that pops up. I want it to show exactly eight lines, with a scrollbar appearing if it's too long and empty cells appearing if it's too short. Instead, it shows all the lines.

While I'm at it, how do I control the width of the JList? I can only find how to control the length.

Comment: Consider showing us your attempts at these with [sscce](http://sscce.org). It's your best shot at showing us what may be wrong with your code and how we can best help.

Comment: It sounds like you've been messing with the `preferredSize` of the components.  `JList` has allows you to supply a [`prototypeCellValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setPrototypeCellValue%28E%29) which the `JList` uses to determine it's preferred size.  You can also use `setVisibleRowCount`, `setFixedCellHeight` and `setFixedCellWidth` to supply values to allow the `JList` to make these calcaultations, but to be frank (other then the visible row count), `setPrototypeCellValue` will give you the best results